# Macro to delete Rows containing #N/A

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the development of VBA Macro for Excel 2013.
I work with large data files created after running a query macro to obtain data from a SQL server. The data file generated by the query file always have a a date:time stamp in Column A, and process results in the other columns (user pre-defined tags) the date:time stamp is essential because the data file is used by another application to analyze and generate reports. The raw data file contains at times a "0" value in some of the rows. A macro is run to remove the "0" values and copy value above.

1st Scenario

1st problem is, where data is not available for a date:time the data sheet displays #N/A in  cells. At times complete rows will display #N/A, with the time stamp in Column A. A Macro is then run to remove #N/A from the sheet. The sheet has then to be manually manipulated to delete the rows with no values except the time stamp.
I need help with a Macro to delete rows that are empty except for column A with date:time stamp, the complete rows have to be deleted.

2nd Scenario

At times the #N/A will be in a column cell with values above, below, left and right of the cell, this #N/A row must not be deleted but must be the value above because of the other application data calculation.

The manual manipulation of the data sheets is very time consuming, after the files are corrected it is saved as "csv" and imported to the other application.

I have tried many conditional macros but no luck.

Is there somebody that can help

I will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution.  The following macro will remove all rows in which the only value is in column A:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim N As Long, NN As Long
    Dim r As Range
    NN = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For N = NN To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Cells(N, "A")
        If wf.CountA(r) = 1 And wf.CountA(r.EntireRow) = 1 Then
            r.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next N
End Sub
```